# onActivityCreated deprecation : how to add fragments as observers of MainActivity using NavigationComponent

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-jetpack

I just saw that onActivityCreated() is going to be deprecated in future. I try to implement LifecycleOwner and LifecycleObserver pattern but I'm not quite sure about what I'm doing here.

I'm using NavigationComponent, which meens :

- I have a MainActivity
- I have a MainFragment, instanciated as the home fragment
- I have multiple fragments that can be accessed from this home fragment

For some reasons I need to know when activity is created from all of these fragments (MainFragment and sub fragments)

From what I've seen until now, I need to :

- In the MainActivity, `getLifecycle().addObserver(new MainFragment())`. And do this for all sub fragments (which is verbose for nothing)
- In fragments, implements LifecycleObserver and

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
private void onCreateEvent() {
    Timber.i("%s MainActivity created", TAG);
}
```

This seems to work well, but I have some questions :

1. The syntax `addObserver(new MainFragment()` disturbs me. It looks like we are creating a new fragment instance, while the fragment is normally instantiated with the navigation defined in the navGraph.
2. As I said before, if I have my MainFragment with 10 sub fragments, I'll have to declare 11 observers ? Weird
3. Do I have to clear these observers at some point in the activity lifecycle ?

What is the proper way to implement it ?

**EDIT 1:**
To answer the question why I need to know when the activity is created :
I need this because I need to access my MainActivity viewmodel (`new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ViewModel.class)`. To call `requireActivity()` or `getActivity()` I need to know when the activity is created (was easy with onActivityCreated()).
Databinding is implemented with my MainActivity and this viewmodel. The layout of this activity is hosting a loader to show when network requests are performed.
I can perform requests from the MainFragment and from the sub fragments. When I perform a request from one of these fragments I need to enable this loader view, and when I got datas back I need to hide this loader.
And yes, all these fragments are in the graph

Comment: "For some reasons I need to know when activity is created" - can you explain exactly what these reasons are? Can you include what code you currently have in `onActivityCreated()`? Also how does your `MainFragment` and the "sub" fragments relate to your use of the Navigation Component? Are they all in the graph or something else?

Comment: I edited the post to answer your questions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have never needed to wait for `onActivityCreated()` to call `requireActivity()` or `getActivity()` - those are both available as soon as the Fragment is attached to the FragmentManager and hence can be used in `onAttach()`, `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()`, `onViewCreated()` all before `onActivityCreated()` is called.

This is one of the reasons why `onActivityCreated()` was deprecated - it actually has nothing to do with the activity becoming available to the Fragment, nor does it have anything to do with the activity finishing its `onCreate()` (it, in fact, can be called multiple times - every time the Fragment's view is created, not just once after the first time the Activity finishes `onCreate()`).

As per the [deprecation notice](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)):

> use [`onViewCreated(View, Bundle)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle)) for code touching the Fragment's view and [`onCreate(Bundle)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) for other initialization.

Those are the recommended replacements, depending on whether the code you had in `onActivityCreated()` was accessing the Fragment's views or not.

Once you realize that `requireActivity()` can be called in `onAttach()`, etc., the rest of the [deprecation notice](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) makes more sense:

> To get a callback specifically when a Fragment activity's [`Activity.onCreate(Bundle)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) is called, register a [`LifecycleObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleObserver) on the Activity's Lifecycle in [`onAttach(Context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onAttach(android.content.Context)), removing it when it receives the [`Lifecycle.State.CREATED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State#CREATED) callback.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    // Register a LifecycleObserver on the Activity's Lifecycle in onAttach()
    requireActivity().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
private void onCreateEvent() {
    // Remove the LifecycleObserver once you get a callback to ON_CREATE
    requireActivity().getLifecycle().removeObserver(this);

    // Then do your logic that specifically needs to wait for the Activity
    // to be created
    Timber.i("%s MainActivity created", TAG);
}
```

But, as mentioned above, this is **not** what you should be doing if you are trying to access a ViewModel at the activity level.

Comment: I remember having a NPE using getActivity() or requireActivity() (or maybe getContext() or requireContext(), I don't remember ?), that's why I thought I should call these methods in onActivityCreated(). It all makes sense now, cause as you stated onActivityCreated()'s naming is misleading regarding what's the purpose of it. Thank you for this clear explanation, very helpful.