# Is it safe to call `getActivity()` from `onCreateView`?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

Looking at the Fragment lifecycle (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339811/when-is-onattach-called-during-the-fragment-lifecycle)), the Activity seems to be attached to the Fragment before any other callback is issued (this is notified by the `onAttach()` method).

In my application, which consist of a single activity, the first Fragment is opened from the `onCreate()` method of the Activity (actually it is the last thing done inside `onCreate()`).

Currently, I'm initializing all my graphical elements inside the `onCreateView()` callback, including the instantiation of some object (like an `ArrayAdapter`) which require the Activity to be constructed, which is obtained calling `getActivity()`. I assume that the Activity is guaranteed to exist at this point, since the `onAttach()` method has already been called.
I noticed that IntelliJ warned me about the possibility of `getActivity()` returning `null`, maybe just because the method is annotated as `@Nullable`, so I started to search on the web if my assumption was actually true, and now I'm confused: is it actually safe to call `getActivity()` inside `onCreateView()`? Why is there a method called `onActivityCreated()` (I know it is now deprecated, but it surely served a purpose when it wasn't)?

Unfortunately the documentation does not help to understand this.

Comment: you can call that inside onCreateView(), but for best practice its required to check getActivity() is null or not, because android doesnt know when you will deattach the fragment, so it will show the warning to prevent it from crash.

Comment: yes.. but better to use `requireActivity()` for null safety

Comment: @NehaK is it actually possible to detach the Fragment before onCreateView is called?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the [official Fragment lifecycle documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#fragmentmanager):

> FragmentManager is also responsible for attaching fragments to their host activity and detaching them when the fragment is no longer in use. The Fragment class has two callback methods, `onAttach()` and `onDetach()`, that you can override to perform work when either of these events occur.

So between `onAttach()` and `onDetach()`, `getActivity()` will always return a non-null `Activity` and that page continues in saying:

> `onAttach()` is always called before any [Lifecycle state changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#states).
>
> `onDetach()` is always called after any [Lifecycle state changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#states).

So, yes, `onCreateView()`, being a lifecycle state change, will mean that `getActivity()` returns a non-null value.

This is exactly the use case for `requireActivity()` - it allows you to tell the fragment system that you *know* at that point in time that `getActivity()` will return a non-null value and you'd like a compile time guarantee that any code following your `requireActivity()` call have access to a non-null Activity.

As for `onActivityCreated()`, it is an incredibly badly named method as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64176532/1676363):

> You have never needed to wait for `onActivityCreated()` to call `requireActivity()` or `getActivity()` - those are both available as soon as the Fragment is attached to the FragmentManager and hence can be used in `onAttach()`, `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()`, `onViewCreated()` all before `onActivityCreated()` is called.
>
> This is one of the reasons why `onActivityCreated()` was deprecated - it actually has nothing to do with the activity becoming available to the Fragment, nor does it have anything to do with the activity finishing its `onCreate()` (it, in fact, can be called multiple times - every time the Fragment's view is created, not just once after the first time the Activity finishes `onCreate()`).

Of course, note that APIs like `ArrayAdapter` do *not* require an Activity - they require a `Context`. There are similar methods in `getContext()` and `requireContext()` that are preferred if you are specifically looking for a `Context`.